# Updating old Web Forms app to work with Chrome/window.open behavior. How to make parent OF PARENT refresh on window close?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, cross-browser, page-lifecycle

I'm trying to update a weird, old ASP.NET Web Forms app that was previously only supported on IE but now needs to run on modern browsers. I've been doing most of my testing on Chrome.

The issue I'm running into at the moment is with the app's page refresh behavior after closing certain popups that the app uses for data entry. In particular, there's one workflow where the main/"console" page spawns a popup, and then that popup spawns its own popup.  When the second popup closes, the old version of the app would actually refresh the console page (which would be the parent of its parent). I don't know how to get this behavior working in Chrome.

The main thing I have done so far is replace the instances of the deprecated "window.showModalDialog()" method with "window.open()". This is how the app had been opening popups, and showModalDialog() does not function at all on Chrome.

This gets the popups working again, but the refresh behavior is all screwy now, even in IE.

The next thing I tried was to use window.opener.location.reload() on the popup pages in a window.onunload function. This allowed me to refresh the console page, but at the wrong time - the refresh seems to happen when the popups open, rather than when they close. I'll explain more below...

I'm not sure what the relevant pieces of code are, but I'll try to capture what I think is important - let me know if more would help!

Here's the JavaScript on the console's .aspx page that's responsible for opening the first popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeNotificationType() {
                var width = screen.width;
                var height = screen.height;

                var w = 550;
                var h = 125;

                var systemZoom = width / window.screen.availWidth;
                var left = (width - w) / 2
                var top = (height - h) / 2

                var myWin = window.open('ChangeNotificationType.aspx', '',
                    'height=' + h / systemZoom + ', width=' + w / systemZoom + ',
                    resizable=yes, status=no, scrollbars=no, toolbar=no, 
                    top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

                return false;
            };
</script>
```

And here's the .aspx.vb code-behind for the button that opens that popup:

```
Protected Sub lnkChangeNotificationType_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'some other code...

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "notification", 
        "<script language='javascript'>changeNotificationType();location.href=location.href</script>")

    'some more code...

End Sub
```

And here's the JavaScript and markup for the first popup:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function createCommitteeVotes() {
            var width = screen.width;
            var height = screen.height;

            var w = 700;
            var h = 700;

            var systemZoom = width / window.screen.availWidth;
            var left = (width - w) / 2
            var top = (height - h) / 2

            var myWin = window.open('AddCommitteeVotes.aspx', '', 
                'height=' + h / systemZoom + ', width=' + w / systemZoom + ', 
                resizable=yes, status=no, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, 
                top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

            return false;
        }

window.onunload = refreshParent;

function refreshParent() {
            window.opener.location.reload();
        }

</script>

//a bunch of markup...

<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" 
    ToolTip="Save Changes" CssClass="CommandButton" />
```

And the first popup .aspx.vb code-behind:

```
Protected Sub btnSaveChanges_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveChanges.Click

    'Code, code, code...

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "committeeVotes", 
        "<script language='javascript'>createCommitteeVotes();window.close();</script>")

    'More code...

End Sub
```

And finally, some .aspx markup from the second popup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveChanges" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" 
    ToolTip="Save Changes" CssClass="CommandButton" />
```

Second popup code-behind:

```
Protected Sub btnSaveChanges_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveChanges.Click

    'Code

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "closeWindow", 
        "<script language='javascript'>window.close()</script>")

End Sub
```

So, my expected results based on previous behavior using IE and showModalDialog():

1. Closing the first popup (ChangeNotificationType) either a) refreshes the console (parent) page or b) opens the second popup if a certain dropdown option is selected.
2. Closing the second popup a) closes the first popup automatically and b) refreshes the console (parent of parent, technically, I think).

The actual results I'm seeing after my swap to window.open():

1. Opening and closing the first popup refreshes the console page (okay...).
2. OPENING the second popup (from the first) refreshes the console page (not really necessary).
3. Closing the second popup still closes the first automatically, but does NOT refresh the console page. This is where the main problem lies.

Were I able to write this site from the ground up, I probably wouldn't write it this way at all... but I'm just trying to give it a simple update without breaking too much.

Any advice, as always, is much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this will help but have a look at [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) (as alternative to `window.onunload`). Check the 'Notes' section.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried replacing where I have the window.unload function with an analogous window.beforeunload function, but it didn't seem to work. Now I get a warning asking me if I'm sure I want to leave the page when I hit the save/submit button on the first popup, the the refresh it causes makes the first popup come up again on top of the second popup.

Comment: Too bad. Was just a thought. I'm not too familar with popups so someone else will have to chime in unless i get some extra time to look further.

Comment: I'm just about to dig into the same issue. Curious if you ever figured this out?

Comment: I never did, sorry!  I ended up sort of re-engineering the page to get around this. Been so long now that I can't remember how, and no longer have access to that code base. Good luck!!